# Bootstrap push, pull not aligning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to achieve a somewhat special design with three blocks. As recomended I started mobile first :

```
-------------------
|       Title     | 
-------------------
|      Image      |
|                 |
-------------------
|      Text       |
|       ...       |
-------------------
```

But starting on tablets I want the following to happen:

```
|-------------------------|
|             |   Title   |
|   Image     |-----------|
|             |           |
|             |   Text    |
|-------------------------|
```

But instead the following shows:

```
|-------------------------|
|             |   Title   |
|   Image     |-----------|
|             |           
|             |           
|-------------------------|
              |           |
              |   Text    |
              |-----------|
```

My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-md-pull-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="url" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-md-push-6">
            <h4>Title of text</h4>
            <p>Wall of text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to split the title & text into one column, and the image into another column

Comment: @Lee and how would I get the image between title and text on small devices?

Comment: unfortunately, you wouldn't be able to. Unless you have two seperately arranged blocks, one for mobile view and one for tablet view that are coded differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md text-center">
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    Image
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-center hidden-xs">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Title of text</h4>
        <p>Wall of text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Way to think out of the box. It's not very elegant but it gets the job done. Thanks.